# Existe alguma maneira de detectar o segundo monitor/ecrã com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tela

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de detectar a existência de um segundo monitor com Javascript.

Em um cenário onde eu estivesse usando dois monitores/ecrãs no meu computador, eu gostaria abrir uma popup através de `window.open` e movê-la para um segundo monitor/ecrã, em tamanho total.

Seria possível fazer isso com Javascript?

Sei que talvez não exista algo nativo, mas talvez deva existir alguma maneira engenhosa, com cálculos, para se detectar isso.

Andei dando uma pesquisada e vi que o objeto [`window.screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) parece trazer alguma informação interessante sobre o monitor/tela do usuário.

Seria esse o caminho?

Comment: PS: Não editem *ecrã*, pois coloquei para ajudar quem é de Portugal :p

Comment: Acho que não tem como de fato detectar com certeza a existência de dois monitores, mas [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7b680e09-0145-4f5e-97ca-158fa563f7ae/how-can-i-detect-whether-there-are-dual-monitors-connected-to-the-computer-by-using-javascript?forum=iewebdevelopment) no MSDN, citaram que se ```screen.width > (screen.height * 1.78)```, provavelmente o usuário está com dois monitores lado a lado, pois resulta em um aspecto maior que 16:9. Mas também não funciona caso sejam dois monitores um em cima do outro.

Comment: @ArturoTemplário, há atualmente o widescreen que tem a proporção de 21:9, é um monitor apenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não existe, é quase impossível mover para a segunda tela**, deve ter uma meia dúzia de gambiarras que promovem por aí dizendo funcionar, mas não é algo que responda corretamente, variando não só de navegador para navegador, mas principalmente de sistema operacional para sistema operacional.

Coisas como calcular a largura e tentar definir o no `left` do `window.open` não vão funcionar. Talvez em sistemas antigos, talvez no Windows XP funcione, mas hoje o sistema de múltiplas telas é "mais complexo", então mesmo que teoricamente você consiga detectar que existe uma segunda tela (como calcular o ratio para supor que aquilo não é uma medida convencional) você não iria conseguir fazer de maneira programada o mover para a segunda tela.

O que realmente falta é uma API nativa para JavaScript que faça isso de maneira simples, na verdade devo dizer que até mesmo `window.open` poderia ter melhorado um pouco mantendo uma retro-compatibilidade para os códigos legados, mas realmente eu não creio que isto seja de interesse.

Vou lhe confessar, a mesma necessidade que você tem de controlar uma janela para ser exibida em outra tela eu tive, tantas foram as dificuldades com as limitações dos navegadores e APIs JavaScript que eu tomei uma simples e unica decisão: migrei para o `Qt`, inicialmente usando `QtWebkit` e posteriormente `QtWebEngine` (tecnologia do Chrome). Então criei uma interface JavaScript que se comunicava com a software, assim eu mesmo disponibilizei um controle de monitores/ecrã. A minha necessidade era simples, o sistema abre no navegador que eu criei e dentro do sistema tinha um link exibir produto para o cliente, que deveria exibir no monitor que fica em cada mesa apenas o produto, e foi assim que cheguei a única solução viável, pois penso eu que para criar sites controle de monitores é realmente dispensável e se for para usar em um sistema interno então você deveria pensar em uma solução menos "WEB", ao menos no caso desta situação especifica, já que exibir em outra tela realmente parece uma necessidade bem especifica e provavelmente não seria para todos usuários.

Eu não estou simplesmente dizendo, **corram para as montanhas**, **abandonem o WEB**, não é isso, entendo que tem muita gente que está no web pela praticidade, pela facilidade de correr a aplicação em diversos dispositivos, mas existem soluções para o mundo HTML e JavaScript de maneira fácil e descomplicada, sem ter que apelar para coisas como C++, Python, Java e ser obrigado a aprender algo novo, um exemplo ótimo disto é o Electron:

- https://electronjs.org

Com ele é possivel criar aplicações desktop com tecnologias HTML, css, js e que vai correr em diversas plataformas.

Aplicações de grande uso usam tal tecnologia, como:

- Github Desktop
- Skype
- Atom
- VisualStudio Code