# Click automático junto com full screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um site, e no site o usuário quando fizer o login vai entrar em um página e essa página deve ficar full screen automaticamente sem o usuário precisar clicar em algo.

Li que não é possível o browser ficar full screen sem a permissão do usuário, então pensei em colocar um click automático no site assim que o usuário entrar, mas ainda sim continua não deixando.

O código que eu tenho:

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('teste').click();

    function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="teste" onClick="toggleFullScreen();"></button>
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso que eu estou precisando?

Comment: Para fazer o login, o usuário provavelmente tem que clicar em algum botão, certo? Você poderia aproveitar a própria ação desse botão para ativar a tela cheia.

Comment: Eu já testei e não vai pq ele direciona pra outra tela

Comment: Boa tarde Maria, existe algo a mais que acha que eu deva incluir na resposta? Ela lhe ficou compreensível?

Answer (score 3):

Isso é inviável, primeiro porque se fosse possível eu realmente como usuário iria me recusar a navegar em diversos sites, que usariam isso indiscriminadamente, muitos usuários leigos iriam ficar perdidos sem saber o que fazer ou irritados, a própria API é determinada para ser assim, o usuário decide o que quer e o que é melhor para ele.

**Forçar um clique automático também não vai funcionar**, o navegador sabe muito bem a diferença de quando o clique é simulado via JS e quando ele é feito pelo usuário (ou um software que simule o usuário).

O navegador é do usuário, logo a intenção de usar um navegador é ele poder usar as abas e janelas, na verdade com o perdão da palavra, mas isto de **forçar o fullscreen é perfumaria**, navegadores não são software finais para uso exclusivo, a premissa é a mesma que respondi em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301222/3635

Eu vou pegar a parte que importa para o entendimento:

> ...**se for para usar em um sistema interno (sistema da empresa)
>   então você deveria pensar em uma solução menos "WEB"**, ao menos no caso
>   desta situação especifica, já que exibir em outra tela realmente
>   parece uma necessidade bem especifica e provavelmente não seria para
>   todos usuários.
>
> **Eu não estou simplesmente dizendo, *corram para as montanhas, abandonem o WEB***, não é isso, entendo que tem muita gente que está no web pela
>   praticidade, pela facilidade de correr a aplicação em diversos
>   dispositivos, mas existem soluções para o mundo HTML e JavaScript de
>   maneira fácil e descomplicada, sem ter que apelar para coisas como
>   C++, Python, Java e ser obrigado a aprender algo novo, um exemplo
>   ótimo disto é o Electron:
>
> - https://electronjs.org
>
> Com ele é possível criar aplicações desktop com tecnologias HTML, css,
>   js e que vai correr em diversas plataformas.
>
> Aplicações de grande uso usam tal tecnologia, como:
>
> - Github Desktop
> - Skype
> - Atom
> - VisualStudio Code

Então simplesmente se deseja criar um software para empresa e limitar o acesso do usuário a este software, eletron ou uma plataforma que use webViews, como Qt, ou aqueles "derivados" com WebKit (tecnologia usada no Safari e em alguns mobiles) como [WebkitGTK+](https://webkitgtk.org) (Qt é C++, GTK é C mas provavelmente vai conseguir usar com C++), claro que o Eletron para quem é mais Web vai ser um caminho bem menos doloroso.

### Electron fullscreen

Um exemplo encontrei neste link https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindow-setfullscreen-flag, deve ficar assim:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let win = new BrowserWindow({ fullscreen: true })
win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
})

win.loadURL('https://seusite.com/login')
```

Para criar o "executavel" (deploy), leia isto:

- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution
- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution#rebranding-with-downloaded-binaries

Para Windows e para MacOS as coisas são diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Ao envés de usar um `<button>` usa este evento no seu HTML:
`<body onClick="toggleFullScreen();">`
Isso significa que se o usuario clicar em qualquer parte da tela o modo FullScreen será ativado.
Esta é a forma mais simples para não ter que ver este erro:
`Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`
Outra solução que encontrei foi:

```
var src = "https://google.com.br";
window.open(src,"newWin","width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight);
```

mas nesse caso o navegador abrirá uma nova janela maximizada, sei que ainda não é isso que você quer, mas estou pesquisando.

Comment: Não é isso que eu preciso, preciso que ele nao precise clicar em nada para isso acontecer, que a página só em carregar faça esse serviço

Comment: eu entendi o que você precisa, também tive essa necessidade um tempo atrás, mas ainda não achei a solução