# Simular Click automático ao carregar página HTML

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse Botão, e desejo que fique invisível:

```
<input type="button" id="invisivel" value="" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">
```

Gostaria que quando a página carregasse esse botão fosse clicado automaticamente.

Tenho esse `script`, mas não funciona:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("invisivel").click();
}, 2000);
```

Script do `toggleFullScreen`:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
                    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
                     (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
                      if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
                        document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
                      } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
                        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
                      } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
                        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
                      }  
                    } else {  
                      if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
                        document.cancelFullScreen();  
                      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
                        document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
                      } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
                        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
                      }  
                    }  
                  }
```

Pelo o que entendo ele clica da um click após 2 segundos, infelizmente não está funcionando. Gostaria que quando carregasse a página o botão fosse clicado automaticamente.

Comment: O botão já está invisível ao carregar a página, o que ocorre ao executar o evento click, é a execução da função `toggleFullScreen()`, que você não mostrou no conteúdo da pergunta.

Comment: Exatamente isso, pois executar a função `toggleFullScreen` está funcionando perfeitamente, a minha pergunta é: simular o click automático desse `button`ao carregar a página.

Comment: @bfavaretto ele disse automaticamente, isso presume que ele quer que o fullscreen seja ativado automaticamente, o que é impossivel e também tenho certeza que isso seria irritante ao usuário final, como respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306227/3635 ... troquei as dups

Comment: "index.html:19 Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture." O google chrome me mostra isso no console.

Comment: @guilherme ok, essa dup é melhor mesmo

Comment: @Benilson traduzindo a frase, o que o navegador disse foi: "Esta API só pode ser iniciada por um gesto de usuário", ou seja só interações reais de usuário funcionam, simular é impossivel, o navegador sabe a diferença, como eu expliquei na minha resposta (linkada acima)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, estou acostumado com inglês, mas as vezes esqueço que outros podem não estar, obrigado por traduzir.

Comment: "mozRequestFullScreen() está obsoleto. index.html:17:49
A solicitação de tela inteira foi negada porque Element.requestFullscreen() não foi chamado a partir de um event handler de curta duração criado por um usuário." Console do firefox, esse já veio em português.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso, você pode tirar o evento click:

```
   document.onload=toggleFullScreen();
```

Comment: Não aconteceu nada, carrego a página e não clica.

Comment: @Expresso1002, fiz uma alteração na resposta, agora vai funcionar

Comment: Não entendi, tirar o evento click?

Comment: Caro Adjair isso não funciona, recomendo que leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306227/3635

Comment: Caro @GuilhermeNascimento, fiz o teste e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: @AdjairCosta entrou em fullscreen ao carregar a página? Em que navegador foi isto?

Answer (score 0):

Basta chamar o [`click()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) do javascript

Para executar a chamada no carregamento da página, deve ser chamada dentro do evento `window.onload`

Exemplo:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("elementName").click();
}
```

O parâmetro `elementName` será o `id` do seu código HTML.

Função de teste:

```
function msgWelcome(){
    alert("Ei, seja bem vindo")
}
```

Chamada no seu HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="elementName" value="" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="msgWelcome()">
```

Testa dessa forma, pois é para funcionar.

Comment: Não funcionou mano, a página carrega mas não acontece nada.

Comment: Então, você não definiu uma ação para o botão, o botão é invisível e não executa nenhuma outra ação, logo não vai acontecer NADA mesmo, recomendo definir melhor o que você precisa.

Comment: Mas eu defini sim, está no contexto.

Comment: Olha, `onclick="toggleFullScreen()"`  não está definido, o que a função ``oggleFullScreen` faz? você tem o código dela pronta? posta ela para nós, edita sua pergunta e passa ela.

Comment: Postei na pergunta.

Comment: Caro Wagner isso não funciona, recomendo que leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306227/3635