# Full Screen - JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso de ajuda caro amigos, abaixo tenho um código para fazer com que a página fique em FULL SCREEN, mais preciso clicar no botão toda vez que entro na página para que fique em FULL SCREEN.

Gostaria que toda vez que entra-se na página o script já executava automaticamente e entrava em FULL SCREEN sozinho.

**Segue abaixo meu código HTML:**

```
<body onload="scree()">
<div>
    <button id="request">Request</button>
</div>
```

**Segue abaixo código JS:**

```
<script>
function scree() {

    $('#request').click(function() {
        screenfull.request($('#container')[0]).then(function() {
            console.log('Browser entered fullscreen mode')
        })
    });
    screenfull.on('change', fullscreenchange);
    fullscreenchange();
}</script>
```

Estou utilizando a biblioteca [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/), poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Caro João, sso é inviável, primeiro porque se fosse possível eu realmente como usuário iria me recusar a navegar em diversos sites, que usariam isso indiscriminadamente, muitos usuários leigos iriam ficar perdidos sem saber o que fazer ou irritados, a própria API foi criada para ser assim, precisar que o usuário interaja, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/306227/3635

Comment: Se houvesse essa possibilidade de entrar num site em full-screen sem autorização prévia rapidamente surgiriam páginas span clonando a interface de navegadores.